# Ember routing through a nested tree

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to allow navigation through a tree along with providing full URLs.
I have an example at: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wurez/2/edit

My data current exists like:

```
App.FamilyMember = DS.Model.extend({
  parents: DS.hasMany('familyMember'),
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 'GP-A',
    name: 'GP A'
  },
  {
    id: 'GP-B',
    name: 'GP B'
  },
  {
    id: 'GP-C',
    name: 'GP C'
  },
  {
    id: 'GP-D',
    name: 'GP D'
  },
  {
    id: 'P-A',
    name: 'P A',
    parents: ['GP-A', 'GP-B']
  },
  {
    id: 'P-B',
    name: 'P B',
    parents: ['GP-C', 'GP-D']
  },
  {
    id: 'P-C',
    name: 'P C',
    parents: ['GP-C']
  },
  {
    id: 'C-A',
    name: 'C A',
    parents: ['P-C']
  },
    {
    id: 'C-B',
    name: 'C B',
    parents: ['P-B']
  },
    {
    id: 'C-C',
    name: 'C C',
    parents: ['P-A']
  }
];
```

I would like to enable a URL along the lines of `/family/GP-A/P-A` and display breadcrumbs of `GP A` -> `P A` at the top of the page. This scenario is N-deep so something along the lines of a grandparent, parent, and child route won't work for me. I am assuming I am going to have to have a route defined along:

```
this.resource('family', function() {
  this.resource('child', { path: '/*id' }, function() {});
});
```

I am not sure if I am going down the wrong path and there is a different approach or how you can implement link-able paths into a tree data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe in general terms the technique I used recently in code that is long and also does not belong to me, so I cannot share it.  The code I include here is just typed in without running or testing  :)

I will assume your nodes are all of the same type.  Since all objects of the same type have a unique ID, your URL pattern only needs to have the ID of the node to which you want to link.  So your URL will be something like `/node/123`

In my case, I created a property on my `ObjectController` called `tree`:

```
App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    parent: DS.belongsTo('node', {inverse: 'children'}),
    children: DS.hasMany('node', {inverse: 'parent'});
});

App.NodeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    tree: [],
    recursiveTreeWalker: function(result, resolve, model) {
        var self= this, parent= model.get('parent');
        if (parent) {
            parent.then(function(resolvedParent) {
                result.push(resolvedParent);
                self.recursiveTreeWalker(result, resolve, resolvedParent);
            });
        }
        else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    },
    treeBuilder: function() {
        var currentNode= this.get('model'), self= this;

        var builder= new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            self.recursiveTreeWalker([], resolve, self.get('model'));
        });
        builder.then(function(tree) {
            self.set('tree', tree);
        }
    }.property('model')
};
```

To describe what's happening, I trigger on model change the call to `treeBuilder`.  This creates a `Promise`, waits for it to resolve with the answer and sets the controller's `tree` variable.  The promise calls `recursiveTreeWalker`, which pushes onto the result an object used by your template.  If it has a parent, it calls itself recursively.  The reason this is called inside a `Promise` is that you need to fully 'realize' the parent node in the tree walker.  In the end, the `tree` variable will contain an ordered list, selected node toward the root of the tree.  My solution actually needed to include the selected node's siblings back toward the root, so each level in the result was another array.

Finally, your template:

```
<ul>
{{#each tree}}
    <li>
        {{#link-to 'node' this}}{{this}}{{/link-to}}
    </li>
{{/each tree}}
</ul>
```